# how to load a dataset stored in ec2 single node hadoop cluster in spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I'm facing an issue while trying to access a file stored in my ec2 hdfs single node cluster using pyspark. Im facing ConnectException. which port should i use to access the files stored in hdfs within the ec2 instance ?

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From ip-172-31-22-162/172.31.22.162 to ec2-54-191-171-11.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: By default HDFS Runs on 8020 (IPC) Port. Check `fs.default.name` parameter in core-site.xml. Also check if Security group of ec2 machine has inbound access to the machine you are running the python client from.

Comment: Thanks @PRASANNASARAF. all I had to do is give the parameter value of fs.default.name to append with the file path. It works now. thanks for the quick help :)